# How can I use the Gnome clock applet (or equivalent) in Xfce?

Tags: xfce, clock, weather, xfce-panel

I'm using Xfce on Ubuntu 11.04; both the default clock and the Orage applet are vastly inferior to the Gnome 2 clock I was used to that lets you click and display both a calendar and timezones and weather forecasts for locations round the world; I'd like to have that functionality.

xf-applet is meant to allow Gnome panel applets in Xfce and works fine, but the clock applet is not one of those listed...

- Why is this?
- Is it possible to use the clock applet somehow?
- If not, is there some equivalent Xfce thing that combines clock, multiple timezones, and weather forecasts in a single applet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For xfapplet to work:

> Most applets were converted to use the new dbus panel applet api
>   introduced in GNOME 2.32. Xfce only supports the old bonobo-based
>   applets, so a lot of applets are unavailable to Xfce now.
>   <sub>[source](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=107285)</sub>

Thus, to get the majority of gnome-applets to work you need to download *maverick* packages - for example `gnome-applets` and `gnome-applets-data` (v2.30.x)

The clock-applet in gnome however is tied to the `gnome-panel` package.  Due to the number of dependencies, it would be very difficult to downgrade to the version of gnome-panel in maverick.

I'm afraid it looks like xfce doesnt have the combined applet you want :(

Answer (score 4):

I found this page after searching some: [Xfce for Gnome 2 Refugees](http://www.kirsle.net/blog/kirsle/xfce-for-gnome-2-refugees)

That page mentions `xfce4-datetime-plugin`, which has the calendar dropdown.
There are several other nice applets in the `xfce4-goodies` package

Comment: Actually the default clock now also supports a calendar dropdown as far as I can see. The shame is that it doesn't combine the weather (not for one city, and not for multiple). Anyway, living with them separately now